# typeset in ksh93 not working as expected

Tags: shell, ksh, typeset

I thought `typeset` was `ksh`'s `local`, but this fails in `ksh93` 
although it works in all my other `typeset`-supporting shells (bash, yash, zsh, pdksh)

```
#!/bin/ksh -ex

foo(){
    typeset a b
    a=0; b=1
    return
}
a=a; b=b
foo
#confirm that the globals didn't change
[ "$a" = a ] 
[ "$b" = b ]
```

What gives?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`typeset` is ksh93's `private` (using static scoping like `perl`'s `my`, not `local` which does dynamic scoping) only for functions that are declared using the ksh function definition style:

```
function foo {
  typeset var=whatever
  ...
}
```

With the Bourne syntax (or with the `.` command (which btw, can also be used on ksh-style functions)), there's no scoping (except for `$1`, `$2`... `$#` of course). So one can use Bourne-style functions to get the value or change the value or type of a variable in the parent context (though `typeset -n` can also be used for that with the ksh-style.

In ksh88, `typeset` was doing dynamic scoping with both the ksh and Bourne function definition style. According to David Korn, POSIX did not specify ksh's variable scoping on the basis that it was *dynamic* (deemed inferior) which is why he changed it to static scoping for `ksh93` (a complete rewrite).

But in the mean time, other shells have implemented variable scoping and they all did it using *dynamic* scoping to mimic ksh88's.

`zsh` now has a `private` keyword to have scoping similar to `ksh93`'s in addition to `local`/`typeset` with dynamic scoping like in `ksh88`.

To see the difference between static and dynamic scoping, compare:

```
"$shell" -c 'function f { typeset a=1; g; echo "$a"; }
             function g { echo "$a"; a=2; }
             a=0; f'
```

Which with `$shell` == `ksh93` outputs:

```
0
1
```

And with `ksh88` or `bash` outputs:

```
1
2
```

`zsh`:

```
$ zsh -c 'zmodload zsh/param/private
          f() { private a=1; g; echo $a;}
          g() { echo $a; a=2; }
          a=0; f'
0
1
```

To be able to use local scope in code portable to `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh88` `ksh93`, `pdksh`, `yash` or `dash`/`FreeBSD` sh, you could do:

```
[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] && shopt -s expand_aliases
alias shdef= kshdef='#'
if type typeset > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  alias mylocal=typeset
  if (a=1; f() { typeset a=2; }; f; [ "$a" = 2 ]); then
    alias shdef='#' kshdef='function'
  fi
else
  alias mylocal=local
fi
```

And then declare your functions as:

```
kshdef foo
shdef foo()
{
  mylocal var
  var=value
  ...
}
```

In any case, there are many differences between the behaviour of those `local` in the various shells. Beside the dynamic vs static consideration mentioned above, there's whether variables initially get an unset or empty value or inherit the value from the parent scope. And there's the interaction with `readonly`, `unset`, whether `local`/`typeset` is a keyword or builtin (affects split+glob handling)...

There are other implications of using the ksh-style function definition in `ksh93`, see the man page for details.

#### More reading

- http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=767 for the POSIX effort  to standardize local scope in `sh`.
- [List of shells support `local` keyword for defining local variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/493729)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it's possible to get the same effect as `local` in ksh93 in without the `function`-based function definitions? The reason I'm asking is I have a bunch of mostly POSIX code except with local variables and so I thought I'd make it more portable by replacing the `local` declarations with `eval $current_shells_local_keyword $the_variables`.

Comment: @PSkocik, you may want to have a look at https://github.com/modernish/modernish

Comment: @PSkocik, see edit for one approach.

Comment: I like your approach but ksh support wasn't essential, and I ended up ignoring it and simply doing alias local=typeset for yash. With that, my code appears to be correct in dash, bash, yash, posh, and zsh, as long as I don't rely on a specific type of scoping, the local values being auto-initialized to empty (in some shells they aren't), and on local being a keyword ( `local a=$b` is nonportable but `local a="$b"` or `local a; a=$b` appears to work across all the shells). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Even worse, the version of ksh93 on RHEL6.10 (shown as `sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01`) and the version on RHEL7.8 (same version string) have different `typeset` behaviors, similar to the ksh88/ksh93 changes.  For example: `echo $HOME; typeset -u HOME; echo $HOME`.  On RHEL6 this uppercases $HOME.  On RHEL7 this uppercases and clears $HOME.

Comment: @jrw32982, looks more like a bug. Apparently fixed at https://github.com/ksh93/ksh. I'm surprised RHEL 6 (from 2010) would have u+ though. Are you sure that ksh came from redhat?

Comment: By "bug", do you mean the rhel6 behavior or the rhel7 behavior? I can't be 100% sure where it came from. `rpm -q` shows `ksh-20120801-38.el6_10.x86_64` on my rhel6.10 server.  (On my rhel7.8 server it shows `ksh-20120801-142.el7.x86_64`)  I found a copy of that rhel6.10 rpm on the internet and pulled it apart.  The RELEASE file top line says `12-08-01...ksh93u+`.  However the ksh93 binary is a different size than on the server, so I don't know what to think.

Comment: Running `ksh93` from the downloaded package produces `sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01` and `typeset -u` does *not* clear an exported variable, such as HOME.

Comment: @jrw32982, I suspect it's a regression introduced by a later fix (and later fixed upstreams, but not pulled by redhat yet).

Comment: @jrw32982, might have something to do with [CVE-2019-14868](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1757324) which I reported a while back.

Comment: In ksh93, is the expected "correct" behavior that `typeset -u VAR` should clear VAR (in this case an exported environment variable, not inside a function but in the mainline of a script) and uppercase further assignments to VAR, or should it uppercase the current value of VAR (prior to `typeset`) and all further assignments?  I realize that the answer to this type of question is dependent on the particular shell/version being discussed.  Is it clear what the answer is supposed to be for ksh93?

Comment: @jrw32982, `typeset -u var` is meant to turn var to uppercase when called in the global scope, Clearing it (and unexporting it) instead would clearly be a bug to me. One that has already been fixed upstreams it seems as I said earlier.

Comment: The regression would have happened much earlier than that CVE-2019-14868 though. I can see ksh93u already cleared the variable, while ksh93s+ was fine.