# What do `declare name` and `declare -g` do?

Tags: bash

1. What does

   ```
   declare name
   ```

   without providing any option do? Does it declare a string variable's
   name?
2. What does

   ```
   declare -g
   ```

   without providing a variable name do? Does it display the values of
   all the variables with global attribute?

I didn't find answers in the description of `declare` at Bash manual.

Thanks.

Comment: I know I have seen that output in the past (declare -g), but it was not with the declare command...

Comment: Tim, did any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please use the checkmark to tell the system that the question is Answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

Variable handling and scoping in shell and especially `bash` can be very obscure and unintuitive (and sometimes buggy).

`ksh` had `typeset` for a similar feature. `ksh`, `zsh`, `yash` have `typeset`. `bash` has `typeset` as an alias of `declare` for compatibility with `ksh`, `zsh` has `declare` as an alias of `typeset` for compatibility with `bash`. Most shells have `export`, `readonly` and `local` that implement part of what `typeset` does.

One of the reasons why `bash` authors chose `declare` over `typeset` may be because `typeset` does not only set the type, it also *declares* a variable: introduce it in a given scope, possibly with a type, attributes and/or value.

In `bash`, variables can be:

- unknown (like when they never have been set or declared)
- declared (after `declare`)
- set (when given a value, possibly empty).

They can be of different types:

- scalar
- array
- associative array

and have several attributes:

- integer
- exported
- readonly
- all lower-case/upper-case
- named references

(though the distinction between type and attribute can be quite blurry).

Not all combinations of types and attributes are supported or effective.

Now, `declare` declares the variable in the current scope. `bash`, even though it implements dynamic scoping treats the outer-most scope specially. It calls it the *global* scope.

`declare` behaves very differently when it's called in that *global* scope and when in a function (I'm not talking of the kind of separate scope that is introduced by subshells or associated with the environment).

When you do `declare var` inside a function and provided that same variable hadn't been declared in that same scope, it *declares* a **new** variable which is initially unset and that shadows a potential `var` variable that would have been present in the parent scope (the caller of the function).

That's dynamic scoping implemented via some sort of stack. When the function exits, the status, type, attributes and value of the variable as it was when the function was invoked is restored (popped from the stack).

Outside of any function however (in the global scope), `declare` does declare a variable, but does not initialise it as unset if it was set before (same as when using `declare` a second time within the same function scope). If a type is specified, the value of the variable may be converted, though not all conversion paths are allowed (only scalar to array/hash), and attributes may be added or removed.

In `bash`, within a function `declare -g` acts on the variable at the bottom of the stack, in the outer-most ("global") scope.

`declare -g` was inspired from `ksh93`'s `typeset -g`. But `ksh93` implements static scoping where the global scope is different and separate from each function scope. Doing the same with dynamic scoping makes little sense. In all other shells that have `typeset -g` (`mksh`, `zsh`, `yash`), `typeset -g` is used to change some attribute of a variable without instantiating a new local one.

In `bash`, people generally use it for the same purpose, but because it affects the variable of the outer-most scope instead of the current variable, it doesn't always work.

For instance:

```
integer() { typeset -gi "$1"; }
```

To make a variable an integer works in `mksh`/`yash`/`zsh`. It works in `bash` only on variables  that have not been declared *local* by the caller:

```
$ bash -c 'f() { declare a; integer a; a=1+1; echo "$a"; }; integer() { typeset -gi "$1"; }; f'
1+1
$ bash -c 'f() { integer a; a=1+1; echo "$a"; }; integer() { typeset -gi "$1"; }; f'
2
```

Note that `export var` is neither `typeset -x var` nor `typeset -gx var`. It adds the `export` attribute without declaring a new variable if the variable already existed. Same for `readonly` vs `typeset -r`.

Also note that `unset` in `bash` only unsets a variable if it has been declared in the current scope (leaves it declared though except in the global scope; it removes attributes and values and the variable is no longer array or hash; also note that on namerefs, it unsets the referenced variable). Otherwise, it just pops one variable layer from the stack mentioned above. With `bash` 5.0 or above, that can be fixed by setting the `localvar_unset` option.

So to sum up:

```
 declare var
```

When called in a function and if `var` has not been declared before in that same function, declares a variable of type *scalar* with no attributes and that is initially unset.

If called outside of any function or if `var` had already been declared in the same function, it has no effect as we're not specifying any new type or attribute.

```
declare -g var
```

Wherever it's called would declare a `var` in the outer-most ("global") scope: make it *declared*, of type *scalar*, no attribute, no value if it was previously unknown in that scope (which for all intent and purpose is the same as an unknown variable except that it would show in the output of `typeset -p`), or do nothing otherwise.

In any case, you might not be able to access that variable in the context you're running that command:

```
f() { local a; g; }; g() { typeset -g a=123; echo "$a"; }; f
```

outputs nothing.

Comment: Thanks. What documents did you or can I learn about scoping in bash or shells?

Comment: From the manpage of `typeset` of zsh, "the  -g  option forces variables to be created or modified at the global scope".  Why "In all other shells that have `typeset -g` (mksh, zsh, yash), `typeset -g` is used to change some attribute of a variable **without instantiating a new local one**"?   Why  does `f() { declare a; integer a; a=1+1; echo "$a"; }; integer() { typeset -gi "$1"; }; f`  in zsh output `2`, instead of `1+1`?

Comment: Is zsh dynamic scoping?

Comment: In bash, if I am correct, `array` and `associative array` are attributes of variables, and we can  declare them with `declare -a` and `declare -A`.   So what  do you mean by saying   `array` and `associative array` are types of variables?  Are  `array` and `associative array` still attributes of variables?

Comment: @Tim, the documentation of `zsh` there (like that of `yash`, but contrary to that of `mksh` which behaves like `zsh`) is not totally accurate here. See the description in the `mksh` man page for the actual behaviour. `-g` comes from `ksh93` where it did mean _global_ which made sense for a shell with static scoping (where variables are either private to the function or global, you can't access  the variables of another function), but not for dynamic scoping where a function sees the variables of its caller.

Comment: `ksh93` is the only shell that I know with static scoping but `zsh` recently added a new `private` module to allow functions to have private variables which in effect does enable some sort of static scoping. Note that `ksh93` only supports local scoping in functions declared the ksh way (`function f { ...; }`).

Comment: Yes, the distinction between `type` and `attribute` is blurry like I said. You could say that array/hash are attributes that can't be removed like readonly. In ksh88, scalars were just arrays with only the element of indice 0 set. It's very similar in `bash`, but `bash` still creates two different variables if you do `a=1` and `a[0]=1`. `zsh`/`yash` are the ones with very distinct types for scalar and array.

Comment: Thanks. In the manpage of mksh, I didn't find `-g` option of `typeset`. So what does `-g` mean for zsh/mksh? In terms of design, which shells are least obscure and unintuitive? Will learning those shells well first be helpful to learning bash?

Comment: @Tim, `-g` was added relatively  recently to `mksh`. I do mention in this answer what `typeset -g` does in `zsh`/`mksh`/`yash`. There's a risk that learning `zsh` will make you give up on `bash`, so in that sense, it  may not help you to learn `bash` :-). If you want a clear and intuitive shell, look at `rc`

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate why "learning zsh will make you give up on bash"?

Comment: If you happen to know, is zsh at the similar good design level to Powershell?

Comment: @Tim, I can't comment as I don't know Powershell. `zsh`, like `bash` also carries some Bourne and Korn heritage baggage, so won't be as neat as a shell like `rc` that was designed from scratch (and unfortunately those non-technical considerations are the main reason why `bash`/`zsh` are used, but not `rc`). Still, compared to `bash` it has made a lot of better design decisions IMO.

Comment: do you mean zsh "has made a lot of better design decisions IMO"?

Comment: @Tim, yes, that's what I mean. `bash` is mostly a one-man effort behind closed doors. While `zsh` is being designed by several people openly (all code change posted to an open mailing list and discussed  upon). `bash` being the official GNU shell, being POSIX certified and so widely used, developers are in a tight place, when a bad design decision is made, it's hard to change it. The zsh development is more relaxed.

Comment: Thanks. When I asked whether learning zsh well may help understanding bash, what I tried to mean is that if zsh is better and similarly designed to bash,  understanding zsh may help me   linger less around the part of bash which is obscure and likely dropped or changed in future bash releases, and focus on the part of bash which is likely long lasting.

Comment: @Tim, for that, look at the POSIX standard.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas (1) ksh has both dynamic and static scope. (2) A -g option is needed to access the (assumed) parent scope. Otherwise, there is no way to change a variable attributes with a function. (3) A simple re-evaluation of a: `a=$a` will make it contain an integer in bash. (4) zsh has the least portable scripting syntax. Learning zsh is like: [*Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems*](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/). If you plan on a long discussion, please open a chat.

Comment: @Arrow Re: 1 ksh88 has dynamic scope, ksh93 static cope see http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/3283 You could say ksh93 has some form of dynamic scoping through subshell environments or `ksh -c 'code'`. See [bash vs zsh: scoping and \`typeset -g\`](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/382393) for the rest.

Comment: ksh93 has both scopes. Your own example to show that bash has dynamic scope: `ksh -c 'f() { typeset a=1; g; echo $a;};  g() { echo $a; a=2; }; a=0; f'` prints `1 2` (like most shells do). Supposedly ([what you said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375157/232326)) showing dynamic scope.

Comment: @Arrow, no, `typeset` in Bourne-syntax functions doesn't do scoping at all in ksh93, that changed from ksh88. See David Korn's message linked above or http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/8377

Comment: From that link, David Korn words **For ksh93, I restored name() to Bourne shell semantics and modified function name{...} to use static scoping of local variables.**  `name()` has the same scope as all other shells, `function name` is the only having static scope. So, ksh93 has both scopes (As I have already said). @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: If that doesn't convince you, read also there: *My proposal is the following: `name()` functions should allow local variables with **dynamic** scoping.  `function name` functions should allow local variables with **static**
        scoping*. David Korn own words. Crystal clear. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: @Arrow, I suggest you read both those 2010 and 2013 discussions so you can understand better the parts you quote. There's also one currently ongoing (on and off) about adding local scope to POSIX sh which you might be interested in reading. You could also try it for yourself, like with `ksh93 -c 'f() typeset a=2; a=1; f; echo "$a"'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63370/discussion-between-arrow-and-stephane-chazelas).

Comment: You  clearly will not change your position. Nothing else to discuss. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: (1) Is “local” also an attribute?  (It’s not on your list of attributes.)  Or is *scope* a different kettle of fish from *attributes*? (2) You might want to explain what “dynamic scoping” means (*in the answer* in addition to in a comment).

Answer (score 4):

1. `declare name` declares the variable named `name`, without any attribute; you can see its effect using `${name:not set}` for example. The declared variable isn’t an array, and it doesn’t have the integer attribute set, so you could consider it a string variable, but it evaluates to 0 in arithmetic expressions.
2. From the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_BUILTIN_COMMANDS):

   > The `-g` option forces variables to be created or modified at the global scope, even when `declare` is executed in a shell function. It is ignored in all other cases.

   So `declare -g` with no parameters is the same as `declare`.

Comment: Yeah, I was just reading that in the manual and you beat me with the answer. Curious factoid the output of `set` is byte-by-byte the same as `declare` ; I think Jeff also noticed that but his answer is not so clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare name
```

From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins

> Declare variables and give them attributes.

You've not provided any options, so there are no attributes assigned, and the variable `name` is created. No value was provided, so none is assigned.

```
declare -g
```

> The -g option forces variables to be created or modified at the global scope, even when declare is executed in a shell function. It is ignored in all other cases.

Since you aren't providing a `name`, no variable is created, so it is ignored. See for yourself:

```
declare -g > foo
declare > bar
diff foo bar
```

The only difference may be the value of the Bash variables `$_`, and possibly `PIPESTATUS` based on your previous commands; there is no other difference in the returned list of variables.