# bash vs zsh: scoping and `typeset -g`

Tags: bash, zsh

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381782/674

> For instance:
>
> ```
> integer() { typeset -gi "$1"; }
> ```
>
> To make a variable an integer works in `mksh`/`yash`/`zsh`. It works
>   in `bash` only on variables  that have not been declared *local* by
>   the caller:
>
> ```
> $ bash -c 'f() { declare a; integer a; a=1+1; echo "$a"; }; integer() { typeset -gi "$1"; }; f'
> 1+1
> $ bash -c 'f() { integer a; a=1+1; echo "$a"; }; integer() { typeset -gi "$1"; }; f'
> 2
> ```
>
> Note that `export var` is neither `typeset -x var` nor `typeset -gx
>   var`. It adds the `export` attribute without declaring a new variable
>   if the variable already existed. Same for `readonly` vs `typeset -r`.

For bash,

- inside `f` of the first example, what does `integer a`do, to declare a different `a` from the `a` declared inside `f` or to make the `a` declared inside `f` have the global scope? Why does it output `1+1`?
- inside `f` of the second example, does `integer a`  declare `a` with the global scope?  Why does it output `2`?

For zsh, the same questions, except that why the first example outputs `2` instead of `1+1` as for bash?

Am I correct that

- both bash and zsh use dynamic scoping, at least in the examples?
- the option `-g` of `typeset` in both bash and zsh means to declare a nonexisting variable with the global scope, or to change an existing variable to have the global scope?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

- In a programming language with **static scoping**, such as most other programming languages (like C),

  There is a global scope and a local scope for each function.  Variables appearing in a function are either private to the function or global.

  A function can only access either **its** local variables or the global variables. It cannot access the variables of another function (even its  caller) other than via passing by reference.
- In a programming language with **dynamic scoping**,

  a function sees the variables of its caller, and there's a scope for each function of your call tree of the function.  Scoping is like Russian dolls where variables are stacked on top of the other.

  In that stack of scopes, the *global* scope is only special in that it is the bottom-most one, but functions don't necessarily see variables in that scope if  they have been masked as a local variable by any of the function in their call tree. So there is not one global and one local scope.

---

It helps to know the history here.

## 1. ksh93

1. In `ksh93`, **a function, at least one declared with the ksh syntax
   (`function f {...}`)**, follows **static scoping**.

   **Variables declared with `typeset` in a function are local variables of the function.**

   ```
   a=global_a
   function f {
     typeset a=f_a
     g
   }

   function g {
     echo "$a"
   }

   f
   ```

   would output `global_a`.

   `typeset -i var` in a function changes the type of the **local**
   `var` variable, with instantiating it in the function scope if it
   wasn't already.
2. In `ksh93`, **a function declared with the Bourne syntax (`f()    {...}`)** doesn't do scoping at all. In that regard, the code of the function appears as if *embedded* in the caller of the function, so any variable appearing in it will have the same scope as in the caller so either global or local to the top-most function declared with the ksh syntax in its call tree. `typeset` would declare the variable in that top-most function (or in the global scope if there was no ksh-syntax function in its call tree).

   For example, since in ksh-syntax functions, all variables are either private or global,  to
   implement our `integer` as in `bash`,  we'd need to do it either  like:

   ```
   integer() { typeset -i "$1"; }
   ```

   That is **using the Bourne function syntax** that doesn't do scoping at
   all.

   Or **using the ksh syntax**:

   ```
   function integer { typeset -i "$1"; }
   ```

   but to be invoked as:

   ```
   . integer var
   ```

   (that is, by **using `.`**, the code of integer is interpreted in the
   context of the caller like when you call `.` (`source`) on a
   script).

   Or using **the ksh syntax**:

   ```
   function integer { typeset -ni "$1"; }
   ```

   Where **the variable is  passed as a reference** with `-n` like you would do in C
   or most other programming languages.

## 2. All the other Bourne-like shells

**All the other Bourne-like shells** (including ksh88, ksh93 was a complete rewrite  and [the change to static scoping was a (perceived at least) pre-requisite for the functionality to be ever included in the POSIX standard](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/8377)) implement **dynamic scoping**.

1. **A variable declared with `typeset` without `-g` in a function has the local scope of the function.**

   For example, `typeset -i var` would declare the variable local (in the current  function scope)    and set the *integer* attribute.

   For example, in the code at the top, they would all output `f_a`.
   That is, `g` does see the local variable of `f`.

   For another example, if `f` calls `g` that calls `h`. If `h` does
   not declare the `var` variable *local* to its scope, it will see
   `g`'s variable or possibly `f`'s if `g` hasn't declared `var` local,
   or possibly the variable from the bottom-most scope.
2. In all of `bash`, `zsh`,
   `yash`, `mksh`, **one can change the type or value of a variable in a function without making it local to that function using `typeset -g`**. Like with that
   `integer` function in the example you quote. But it's done differently depending on the shell.

   - **In `mksh`, `yash`, `zsh`**, `typeset -g`   doesn't affect the variable at the bottom-most (*global*) scope, but
     **at    the scope it currently been defined**.

     For example, while `typeset -i var` would declare the variable local (in the current  function scope)  and set the *integer* attribute, `typeset -gi var` just does the  latter part (without affecting the scope of `var`).

     For example, when a function calls my `integer` function above to add the integer  attribute to a variable, as in:

     ```
     f() {
      local myvar
      integer myvar
      ...
     }
     ```

     It does want `integer` to change the attributes of **its** `myvar` variable, not the one in the global scope which it has no knowledge of and may not be able to access.
   - **In `bash`**, `typeset -g` affects the instance of the variable **in the global (bottom-most) scope**. While that's what the `g` stands for, it's not useful in shells with dynamic
     scoping like    `bash`.

     For example, in the first example in your
     question, `1+1`    being output shows that the integer attribute has
     not been added to    the variable. It has been added to *a* variable
     `a` in the global    scope, but not the one that the `f` function
     has access to.

Comment: Thanks. Could you paraphrase more directly and/or give some example for explaining "`typeset -gi var` does not give the integer attribute to var without instantiating it in the local scope"? I have been stuck at that sentence.

Comment: I took the liberty to improve the readability of your post. The sentence I asked in my previous comment doesn't make sense to me, so I removed it.

Comment: @Tim, thanks. I've made some corrections to some of them. See edit.