# Global associative array only visible when the script is sourced a second time

Tags: bash, associative-array

I have the following script called `.bash_functions.test` which is already sourced by my `.bash_functions` script:

```
# vim: set syn=sh noet:

mp4Options_BIS="-movflags +frag_keyframe"
declare -A audioExtension=( [libspeex]=spx [speex]=spx [opus]=opus [vorbis]=ogg [aac]=m4a [mp3]=mp3 [mp2]=mp2 [ac3]=ac3 [wmav2]=wma [pcm_dvd]=wav [pcm_s16le]=wav )

function test1 {
    echo "=> mp4Options_BIS = $mp4Options_BIS"
    echo "=> audioExtension = ${audioExtension[*]}"
}
```

And when I run the `test1` function I see this:

```
=> mp4Options_BIS = -movflags +frag_keyframe
=> audioExtension =
```

Finally, when I source the script once more and re-run the `test1` function I see this:

```
=> mp4Options_BIS = -movflags +frag_keyframe
=> audioExtension = ac3 wma opus mp3 wav mp2 wav spx m4a spx ogg
```

In fact, I use my `Source` function in the first source call and the `source` builtin and the second source call:

```
$ grep -r .bash_functions.test 
.bash_functions:source $initDir/.bash_functions.test
$ type Source 
Source is a function
Source () 
{ 
    test "$debug" -gt 0 && time source "$@" && echo || source "$@"
}
```

And here is what happens:

```
$ Source .initBash/.bash_functions.test
$ test1
=> mp4Options_BIS = -movflags +frag_keyframe
=> audioExtension = 
$ source .initBash/.bash_functions.test
$ test1
=> mp4Options_BIS = -movflags +frag_keyframe
=> audioExtension = ac3 wma opus mp3 wav mp2 wav spx m4a spx ogg
```

Why is it working like this?

Comment: Does your `.bash_functions` source `.bash_functions.test` *from within a function* by any chance? If that was the case, the `declare` would cause that associative array to be declared _local_ to that function and you'd need `declare -gA` to make sure the variable is declared in the global scope.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You're right. Can you convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`declare`/`typeset` without `-g` declares variables in the current scope in addition to setting the type.

Here, because `declare -A audioExtension=(...)` ends up being run within the `Source` function, that causes the `audioExtension` variable to be declared local to that function, and as a consequence its definition to be lost once `Source` returns.

You could change it to `typeset -Ag audioExtension=(...)` which always declares the variable in the global scope (it's different from zsh/mksh/yash where `typeset -g` only prevents the variable from being made local (only updates the type/attributes and value); it makes a difference when your `Source` function is called from another function itself; see [bash vs zsh: scoping and `typeset -g`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/382380) for details).

If you used `ksh93` instead of `bash` (that's the shell `bash` borrowed that associative array syntax from), you could define your `Source` function as:

```
Source() {
  ...
}
```

as opposed to:

```
function Source {
  ...
}
```

In ksh93, functions defined with the Bourne-style `func() cmd` syntax don't have a local scope while `function func {` ones have *static* local scope (there, there's only *one* global scope and *one* local per-function scope, not a stack of local scopes).

In `bash` (and other shells with local scoping), there's no similar way to have a function that doesn't introduce a new scope. You could use an `alias` instead like:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
if [ "$debug" -gt 0 ]; then
  alias Source='time source'
else
  alias Source=source
fi
```

(note that the aliases are expanded at the time code is *read*, not at the time it's *executed*).

It would make a functional difference compared to your function approach in that in:

```
Source ./myfile | other-cmd
```

We would be timing both `source myfile` and `other-cmd` as it's expanded to `time source ./myfile | other-cmd` while in the function approach we would only by timing `source ./myfile`.

Using `source=(time source); "${source[@]}" /some/file` wouldn't  work (it would invoke the `time` standalone utility instead of the `bash` time keyword).