# What does unset do?

Tags: bash

I am trying to understand the following part about `unset` from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381782/674

> `unset` in `bash` **only unsets a variable if it has been declared in
>   the current scope** (**leaves it declared though except in the global
>   scope**; it removes attributes and values and the variable is no longer
>   array or hash; also note that on namerefs, it unsets the referenced
>   variable). **Otherwise, it just pops one variable layer from the stack
>   mentioned above.**

Bash manual doesn't mention anything related, or I miss it.

Could you explain with examples for

- "only unsets a variable if it has been declared in the current scope"
- "leaves it declared though except in the global scope".

  If `unset` a variable which is in a function's local scope, is the `unset` variable not just unset but also undeclared?

  If `unset` a variable which is in the global scope, is the `unset` variable just unset but still declared?

  How may I check if a variable is declared or not?
- "Otherwise, it just pops one variable layer from the stack mentioned above."

  What do "otherwise" and "one variable layer" mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Best with examples:

```
$ bash -c 'a=0; f() { local -i a=1; unset a; typeset -p a; a=2; }; f; echo "$a"'
declare -- a
0
```

That's `unset` called on a variable declared in the same scope. It's properly unset. It's still declared (though it has lost attributes and value), it's still limited to that scope. You see that even though we do a `a=2`, that is still done on a `a` local to `f`, the one from the outer scope is not affected. That's good and what we want.

In:

```
$ ./bash -c 'a=0; f() { local a=1; g; a=2; }; g() { unset a; echo "$a"; }; f; echo "$a"'
0
2
```

You can see that `unset a` didn't unset `a`. Instead, it revealed the one underneath, the one from the outer scope. When `g` returns, `f`'s `a` variable will no longer be local.

In bash 5+, that can be fixed by setting the `localvar_unset` option.

Note that it's even worse in `mksh` and `yash` where `unset` does that *popping* instead of *unsetting* even for variables that have been declared in the same scope. The first example with them gives:

```
typeset a=0
2
```

Further reading at:

- https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg19445.html
- http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=767
- https://www.mail-archive.com/miros-mksh@mirbsd.org/msg00702.html