# Why doesn't read command work with echo and piping?

Tags: bash, shell

With regard to the below commands:

```
$ unset a
$ echo 12 | read a
$ echo $a

$
```

I was expecting that a would be set the value of 12 in the second statement. But it turns out that a is still unset.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at this post. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382391/what-does-unset-do

Answer (score 1):

You can use Process Substitution in bash.

```
read -r a < <(echo 12)
echo "$a"
```

Or a `here string` also in bash.

```
read -r a <<< 12
echo "$a"
```

In most shells, each command of a pipeline is executed in a separate SubShell. see [Why I can't pipe data to read.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

You need to use a temp file if the shell you're using does not support Process Substitution and a `here string`

```
echo 12 > tempfile
read -r a < tempfile
echo "$a"
```

Although tempfile is just an example for real life situation scripts a `fifo` or `mktemp` is used and created in a secure manner.