# List of shells that support `local` keyword for defining local variables

Tags: shell-script, shell

I know that Bash and Zsh support `local` variables, but there are systems only have POSIX-compatible shells. And `local` is undefined in POSIX shells.

So I want to ask which shells support `local` keyword for defining local variables?

<strike>**Edit**: About shells I mean the default `/bin/sh` shell.</strike>

Comment: dash supports them, ksh supports them but I think you need to use `typeset` instead of `local`

Comment: @Jesse_b ksh doesn't support the `local` keyword; it does support local variables, but via `typeset` not via the `local`, and only in funcs defined as `function foo { }`, not in funcs defined as `foo(){ }`.

Comment: @pizdelect: thanks for reiterating exactly what I just said

Comment: I discourage from using it if you want POSIX compatibility. I use only pure `#!/bin/sh` scripts.

Comment: @Jesse_b did you miss the part about `typeset` not working in functions defined as `foo(){ ... }`? Example: `foo(){ typeset v=3; }; function bar { typeset v=7; }; v=1; foo; echo $v; bar; echo $v;` => 3, 3.

Comment: Thanks @Vlastimil. I think if most system (e.g. more than 90%) have shell supports `local` variables, then it worth using it to make use of its advantage. We have stuck too long in POSIX shells.

Comment: @mja I don't think you'll ever find a system that doesn't have bash, and if you do work in an environment like that it will be one of the first things you learn about it.

Comment: @Jesse_b FreeBSD has `ash` as default `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Well ubuntu has dash as default, but you didn't say default you said "have shell supports local".  freeBSD does in fact have bash

Comment: @Jesse_b ksh88 doesn't support any kind of local variables. And there are plenty of systems that don't have bash. @mja generally bash, zsh and ash-derived shells (dash, busybox, FreeBSD's /bin/sh) and also pdksh-derived shells (OpenBSD's, mksh, newer android's) do support the `local` keyword.

Comment: @pizdelect:  Please see the [ksh88 manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/ksh88-1.html#scrolltoc).  "Ordinarily, variables are shared between the calling program and the function. However, the typeset special command used within a function defines local variables whose scope includes the current function and all functions it calls."  Also please name a system built in the last 20 years that does not have bash?

Comment: @Jesse_b I don't know about the manual; I've just tried it on a genuine `/bin/ksh` from 1991 ;-). But if it works in some versions, it probably works the same as in `ksh93`.

Comment: @Jesse_b I’ve seen many AIX systems without bash, even new ones set up last year.

Comment: @StephenKitt @Jesse_b @pizdelect Current AIX systems have ksh88 as /bin/ksh, which has incompatibilities around this topic with ksh93.  In ksh88 you don't need `function foo {...}` to get locals using `typeset`, but in ksh93 you do.  That's bad news, if you used the `foo() {...}` syntax, for shell scripts written for ksh88 (AIX) and then ported to ksh93 (Linux),

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's not as simple as supporting `local` or not. There is a lot of variation on the syntax and how it's done between shells that have one form or other of local scope.

That's why it's very hard to come up with a standard that agrees with all. See http://austingroupbugs.net/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=767 for the POSIX effort on that front.

local scope was added first in ksh in the early 80s.

The syntax to declare a local variable in a function was with `typeset`:

```
function f {
  typeset var=value
  set -o noglob # also local to the function
  ...
}
```

(function support was added to the Bourne shell later, but with a different syntax (`f() command`) and `ksh` added support for that one as well later; the Bourne shell never had local scope (except of course via subshells))

The `local` builtin AFAIK was added first to the Almquist shell (used in BSDs, dash, busybox sh) in 1989, but works significantly differently from `ksh`'s `typeset`. `ash` derivatives don't support `typeset` as an alias to `local`, but you can always define one by hand.

bash and zsh added `typeset` aliased to `local` in 1989 and 1991 respectively.

ksh88 added `local` as an undocumented alias to `typeset` circa 1990 and pdksh and its derivatives in 1994. `posh` (based on `pdksh`) removed `typeset` (for strict compliance to the Debian Policy that requires `local`, but not `typeset`).

POSIX initially objected to specifying `typeset` on the ground that it was *dynamic* scoping. So ksh93 (a rewrite of ksh in 1993 by David Korn) switched to *static* scoping instead. Also in ksh93, as opposed to ksh88, local scoping is only done for functions declared with the `ksh` syntax (`function f {...}`), not the Bourne syntax (`f() {...}`) and the `local` alias was removed.

However the ksh93v- beta and final version from AT&T can be compiled with an experimental "bash" mode (actually enabled by default) that  does dynamic scoping (in bother forms of functions, including with `local` and `typeset`) when `ksh93` is invoked as `bash`.  `local` differs from `typeset` in that case in that it can only be invoked from within a function. [That `bash` mode will be disabled by default in ksh2020](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/238) though [the `local`/`declare` aliases to `typeset` will be retained even when the bash mode is not compiled in](https://github.com/att/ast/pull/1379) (though still with static scoping).

`yash` (written much later), has `typeset` (à la ksh88), but has only had `local` as an alias to it since version 2.48 (December 2018).

[@Schily](/users/120884/schily) (who sadly [passed away in 2021](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5861)) used to maintain a Bourne shell descendant which has been recently made mostly POSIX compliant, called [`bosh`](http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html) that supports local scope since version 2016-07-06 (with `local`, similar to `ash`).

So the Bourne-like shells that have some form of local scope for variables today are:

- ksh, all implementations and their derivatives (ksh88, ksh93, pdksh and derivatives like posh, mksh, OpenBSD sh).
- ash and all its derivatives (NetBSD sh, FreeBSD sh, dash, busybox sh)
- bash
- zsh
- yash
- bosh

As far as the `sh` of different systems go, note that there are systems where the POSIX `sh` is in `/bin` (most), and others where it's not (like Solaris where it's in `/usr/xpg4/bin`). For the `sh` implementation on various systems we have:

- ksh88: most SysV-derived commercial Unices (AIX, HP/UX, Solaris¹...)
- bash: most GNU/Linux systems, Cygwin, macOS
- ash: by default on Debian and most derivatives (including Ubuntu, Linux/Mint) though can be changed by the admin to bash or mksh. NetBSD, FreeBSD and some of their derivatives (not macOS).
- busybox sh: many if not most embedded Linux systems
- pdksh or derivatives: OpenBSD, MirBSD, Android

Now, where they differ:

- `typeset` (ksh, pdksh, bash, zsh, yash) vs `local` (ksh88, pdksh, bash, zsh, ash, yash 2.48+).
- the list of supported options.
- static (ksh93, in `function f {...}` function), vs dynamic scoping (all other shells). For instance, whether `function f { typeset v=1; g; echo "$v"; }; function g { v=2; }; f` outputs `1` or `2`. See also how the `export` attribute affects scoping in `ksh93`.
- whether `local`/`typeset` just makes the variable *local* (`ash`, `bosh`), or creates a new instance of the variable (other shells). For instance, whether `v=1; f() { local v; echo "${v:-empty}"; }; f` outputs `1` or `empty` (see also the `localvar_inherit` option in bash 5.0 and above).
- with those that create  a new variable, whether the new one inherits the *attributes* (like `export`) and/or type and which ones from the variable in the parent scope. For instance, whether `export V=1; f() { local V=2; printenv V; }; f` prints `1`, `2` or nothing.
- whether that new variable has an initial value (empty, 0, empty list, depending on type, `zsh`) or is initially  unset.
- whether `unset V` on a variable in a local scope leaves the variable `unset`, or just *peels* one level of scoping (`mksh`, `yash`, `bash` under some circumstances). For instance, whether `v=1; f() { local v=2; unset v; echo "$v"; }` outputs `1` or nothing (see also the `localvar_unset` option in bash 5.0 and above)
- like for `export`, whether it's a keyword or only a mere builtin or both and under what condition it's considered as a keyword.
- like for `export`, whether the arguments are parsed as normal command arguments or as assignments (and under what  condition).
- whether you can declare *local* a variable that was readonly in the parent scope.
- the interactions with `v=value myfunction` where `myfunction` itself declares `v` as local or not.

That's the ones I'm thinking of just now. Check the austin group bug above for more details.

As far as local scoping for shell *options* (as opposed to *variables*), shells supporting it are:

- `ksh88` (with both function definition syntax): done by default, I'm not aware of any way to disable it.
- `ash` (since 1989): with `local -`. It makes the `$-` parameter (which stores the list of options) local.
- `ksh93`: now only done for `function f {...}` functions.
- `zsh` (since 1995). With `setopt localoptions`. Also with `emulate -L` for the emulation mode (and its set of options) to be made local to the function.
- `bash` (since 2016) with `local -` like in `ash`, but only for the options managed by `set`, not the ones managed by `shopt`.

---

<sup>¹ the POSIX `sh` on Solaris is `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` (though it has many conformance bugs including those options local to functions). `/bin/sh` up to Solaris 10 was the Bourne shell (so no local scope), and since Solaris 11 is ksh93</sup>

Comment: Bourne (heirloom version) supports functions as `f() { list; }`.

Comment: @Isaac, it's `f() any-command` (except that if `any-command` is a _simple command_, it can't have redirections). The POSIX syntax is `f() any-compound-command`. `{...}` is both a command and compound command. The Bourne shell initially didn't have functions. Function support was added in SVR2 in 1984 with a different  syntax from that of ksh (1983) which is what I'm saying here.

Comment: @Isaac, the best source of information about the Bourne shell is at https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/index.html

Comment: See also https://web.archive.org/web/20000816225337if_/http://www.cs.princeton.edu:80/~jlk/kornshell/doc/vhll.ps.gz where David Korn mentioned that support for functions in the Bourne shell was added in 1982 (1984 was when SVR2 was released) and the ksh `function f { ....}` predated that (ksh first announced in 1983 AFAIK).

Comment: I came here hunting for 'POSIX compatible way to use local' and found this: http://stchaz.free.fr/locvar.sh

Answer (score 7):

To follow up on a hint in Stéphane's answer, using subshells gets you the local *effect*. I don't have access to a true POSIX shell, but this works in busybox `ash` -- declare your functions with `()` parentheses instead of `{}` braces. That forces the function to run in a subshell.

```
func() (
    echo "in func, before declaring: x=$x"
    x=10
    echo "in func, after declaring: x=$x"
)

x=5
echo "before func: x=$x"
func
echo "after func: x=$x"
```

outputs

```
before func: x=5
in func, before declaring: x=5
in func, after declaring: x=10
after func: x=5
```

That shows that the function has access to global variables, and setting variables in the function does not alter the globals. This is a technique I sometimes use when I want to alter `$IFS` or `cd` to a different directory, but I don't want those actions to affect the rest of the program.

Comment: I presume that back in the early UNIX days, this was the intended way to get local variables and any other local state, if you really needed it, and that's why the early Bourne shell didn't have them. Forking a new process was one simple, universal, composable way to isolate _all_ state, and the shell seems like it was intended as a DSL for calling processes and gluing those processes together with file descriptor redirections, not as a fully-fledged general-purpose language which would be doing enough substantial logic to need local variables.