# Is there a way to make the local command work portably to dash ksh bash and zsh?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, ksh, dash

In dash (and in bash zsh and some other shells) the command `local` works to make a variable scope limited to that function (and descendants in some cases). That enable the possibility of making a variable limited to that function **internals** only (and descendant function calls in some cases).

For example:

```
testlocal(){ 
                local IFS
                IFS=123
                echo "internal  IFS = $IFS"
                testdescend
}

testdescend(){
                echo "descended IFS = $IFS"
}

IFS=abc
testlocal
echo "external  IFS = $IFS"
```

Produce this output on execution in dash (and bash and zsh):

```
$ dash ./script
internal  IFS = 123
descended IFS = 123
external  IFS = abc
```

Which means that the IFS remains **local** to the function (and descendants).

However, ksh is different, doesn't accept `local`:

```
$ ksh ./script
./mt2[3]: local: not found [No such file or directory]
```

Changing the word 'local' to 'typeset' makes the script (almost) work in ksh but dash doesn't recognize `typeset`.

And, to make the scope dynamic (descend to called functions) in ksh, the word `function` must be used to define functions:

```
function testlocal { 
                     typeset IFS
                     IFS=123
                     echo "internal IFS = $IFS"
                     testdescend
                   }
```

Which further complicates portability to dash.

The question is: How to make the original script work also in ksh ?
Is it possible to avoid a test for which shell is running the script?

Comment: Add `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to the top of the file and you're good. Seriously. Trying to write actually portable shell scripts is an exercise in pain and futility, IMO, and maintainers are going to absolutely hate the result. Or you could `./do-the-thing-in-most-shells.sh || ./do-the-thing-in-ksh.ksh`.

Comment: You can often use a subshell instead.

Comment: Just save the value of IFS and restore it afterwards.  Stick to POSIX features if you want portability.

Comment: @Mikel Subshells may be **an order of magnitude slower** ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVHLbsIwELz7K0augbhVAglQ2kRB9FAkDqgS5db2wCNRLAUHYdNXmm@nTqBSq5Ze2MPKO/bOzqznM5XsdjJ0W61WgOh1nW00JFm9iViFLHd92ymCA1yBAVQiYk2mo/Ht8G4yvpmGtQmxLHbGOep1qEjDtuE6XtvvOF3/snflXzst0ExGwDn0S0ZBdbtdFZ0OJSTONoYUQmJp1GBepneVBFhmhMBEvJUhZVZeFVqsIjDzxF6gUSE/Q0dKx67Fc6TZYpZiNLwPyhSyL/17hWxg/C6SDEwEKP4gEqHZyEsi0ggPMOMtcRG6nFPYBqFMUjyVEg8DDTKgVV8Jyij4xdhAv7mMnptym6bVZQGvX3fB6d6l2s6PuMQxm57Fre/g/zbBT3Xpne5yvRFSx2jUugo@aj3Hix9lw/CqhIJZlVTKcrMM3@4WTZabzy9PFB@YL4wqTsrBZLf7BA "Bash – Try It Online"))

Comment: @Wildcard It becomes quite ugly to cover an originally unset IFS.

Comment: Related: [List of shells that support \`local\` keyword for defining local variables](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/493729)

Comment: What implementation/version of ksh is that? AFAIK, ksh88, pdksh and derivatives have dynamic scoping (and only dynamic scoping) with `typeset`/`local` and ksh93 has static scoping only and with `function f {...;}` only and with `typeset` only. `f() {...;}` functions have no local scope at all there.

Comment: See also [typeset in ksh93 not working as expected](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/375156)

Comment: (1) Which shells have a builtin called `local`? : Most of them except ksh93.
(2) I am using ksh93.
(3) Dynamic vs. Static in ksh93 ? Care to explain why [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc/RCsIgGIbhc6/iQwrqcK4z2cWoTSaRG83AiK7d5r8QT4Q8EPnlkdfbOqUUB6UNY/bpTXCzx/JwPkTgDexnC368goMfIkdZEp8K2a5XeZpReC3jOgZEiTh0vSwv7qgyomFE09yV8@pnqrWZi6QISc9SXLnd5vp0/iuuMqJhRNPkuIxacZriNMXRR2jXbDTTzFL6Ag "ksh – Try It Online") prints `14 14 13 12` Is it only Static ?. The ksh93 has both scopes available.
(4) You propose a complex workaround to have the **function** only appear in ksh ? ... @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: The C language, which you should agree that has static scope, [has local variables by default](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm). I believe that that should be the real intent of the builtin `local`. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: @l0b0 the #! has no effect when run as `bash script`

Answer (score 5):

Note ksh88 and all its clones do dynamic scoping and have been supporting `local` for it since at least 1990 for ksh88 and 1994 for `pdksh` (and 1989 for `bash` which (now) implements a lot of the ksh88 API).

The `ksh` you're referring to is `ksh93`, a newer implementation from scratch by David Korn with a slightly different and incompatible API.

It's a good idea to refer to that shell as `ksh93` instead of just `ksh` as `ksh` alone has meant the `ksh88` API for a few decades (the one all but the ksh93 implementations implement). `ksh93` has not been in wide use until a few years after 2000 when its code was released as open source.

ksh93's `typeset` only does *static* scoping. POSIX had objected to specifying ksh88's `typeset`/`local` on the ground that it was dynamic scoping (though, even though most languages like C do *static* scoping, *dynamic* scoping comes more naturally in shells as it's what you get in effect with subshells or with the environment), which explains why ksh93 was rewritten to do static coping.

Later, most other shells implemented scoping a la ksh88, so ksh93 is now the odd one out. And now ironically, POSIX's only reasonable option would be to specify a dynamic scope. While David Korn initially refused to implement dynamic scoping in ksh93, he had said he could consider it with the `local` keyword/builtin on the POSIX mailing list, but he has retired before that fully happened.

The ksh93v- beta and final version from AT&T can be compiled with an experimental "bash" mode (actually enabled by default) that  does dynamic scoping (in bother forms of functions, including with `local` and `typeset`) when `ksh93` is invoked as `bash`. [That `bash` mode will be disabled by default in ksh2020](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/238) though [the `local`/`declare` aliases to `typeset` will be retained even when the bash mode is not compiled in](https://github.com/att/ast/pull/1379) (though still with static scoping).

Now if we leave that beta release aside and its bash mode, ksh93 *only* does static scoping and only in the functions declared with the ksh-style syntax (`function name { code; }`). You're getting confused because the functions declared with the Bourne-style syntax (`f() command`) don't do scoping *at all*. It's the same with sourced files or ksh functions invoked with `. name [args]`. In those, `typeset` doesn't declare a new variable in the function's scope (that function has no scope), it just updates the type of the variable in the current scope which is going to be either the global scope or the scope of a ksh-style function if that Bourne-style was (eventually) called from within a ksh-style function.

The code of Bourne-style functions is run as if embedded/copy-pasted/sourced wherever they're invoked.

```
var=global
function ksh_function {
  typeset var=private
  echo "ksh1: $var"
  bourne_function
  echo "ksh2: $var"
  other_ksh_function other
  echo "ksh3: $var"
  . other_ksh_function other_invoked_with_dot
  echo "ksh4: $var"
}
bourne_function() {
  typeset var=set-from-bourne-function
}
function other_ksh_function {
  echo "other: $var"
  var=$1
}
ksh_function
echo "global: $var"
```

Gives:

```
ksh1: private
ksh2: set-from-bourne-function
other: global
ksh3: set-from-bourne-function
other: set-from-bourne-function
ksh4: other_invoked_with_dot
global: other
```

It's not possible in ksh93 to have dynamic scoping other than by using subshells or implementing a variable stack by yourself like in [that `locvar` proof of concept](https://github.com/stephane-chazelas/misc-scripts/blob/master/locvar.sh) or you *export* the variable for it to be passed to every command (including functions declared with the ksh-style functions, including external commands via the environment).

In your particular case where only the `testlocal` function (and not `testdescend`) need a local scope, you can use the `shdef`+`kshdef` approach as described [there](/a/375157) or do something like:

```
case $KSH_VERSION in
  (*" 93"*)
    fn_with_local_scope() {
      alias local=typeset
      eval "function $1 {
        $(cat)
      }"
    }
  ;;
  (*)
    fn_with_local_scope() {
      eval "$1() {
        $(cat)
      }"
    }
  ;;
esac
```

And then declare your functions as:

```
fn_with_local_scope testlocal << '}'
  local IFS
  IFS=123
  echo "internal IFS = $IFS"
  testdescend
}

testdescend(){
  echo "descended IFS = $IFS"
}

IFS=abc
testlocal
echo "external IFS = $IFS"
```

(and only use `local` in functions declared with `fn_with_local_scope`).

Which gives

```
internal IFS = 123
descended IFS = 123
external IFS = abc
```

in all shells (note that you need a recent version of `yash` (2.48 or above) for it to support `local`).

Or if you're OK for the local variables to also be exported (in ksh93 only):

```
case $KSH_VERSION in
  (*" 93"*)
    fn() {
      alias local='typeset -x'
      eval "function $1 {
        $(cat)
      }"
    }
  ;;
  (*)
    fn() {
      eval "$1() {
        $(cat)
      }"
    }
  ;;
esac

fn testlocal << '}'
  local IFS
  IFS=123
  echo "internal IFS = $IFS"
  testdescend
}

fn testdescend << '}'
  echo "descended IFS = $IFS"
}

IFS=abc
testlocal
echo "external IFS = $IFS"
```

Now, if you were to do something like that in a language with static scoping like C or ksh93, you'd do something like:

```
function testlocal {
  typeset IFS
  IFS=123
  echo "internal IFS = $IFS"
  testdescend "$IFS"
}

function testdescend {
  typeset IFS="$1" # explicitly get the value $IFS from the caller
  echo "descended IFS = $IFS"
}
```

Which seems to me like a better design, and that code would work OK as well in shells that do dynamic scoping (you'd still need to address the different function definition syntax).

Further reading:

- [List of shells that support `local` keyword for defining local variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/493729)
- [typeset in ksh93 not working as expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/375156)

Comment: *ksh93 only does static scoping* False.

Comment: @Isaac, it seems like you're wanting to play on words, so I'm not going to argue with you. I'll leave the answer there in case it can be useful to others.

Comment: @Isaac This is a confusion in terminology.  When Stéphane says "ksh93 only does static scoping", he means ksh93 has both "no scope" and "static scope".  "No scope" means global scope only, i.e. there's only one (global) scope for variables.  Static (or private) scope means that a variable is only visible within the declaring function, not in any children functions, including itself if called recursively.  Dynamic scope means visible **and changeable** by children functions.  In both static and dynamic scope, the previous scope is restored when the function returns to its caller.

Comment: Bash and ksh88 have global and dynamic scopes.  Ksh93 has global and static scopes.  Confusingly, the builtin "local" indicates dynamic scope, not private (static) scope.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375156.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer bash (better array syntax IMO) but encounter ksh scripts sometimes, and so I try to do these when convenient:

Always use `function func_name { body; }` syntax.

Based on the above, to use `local` keyword: before first function, use:

```
# teach ksh 93 about local
case "$KSH_VERSION" in *' 93'*) alias local='typeset -x' ;; esac
```

To get function name inside function: use:

```
local MYNAME="${FUNCNAME[0]:-$0}"
```

Comment: Funny you would say that (*better array syntax IMO*), bash array design was copied from ksh, with all its warts and without including the more advanced features like multi dimensional arrays. For better arrays, look at rc, es, fish, zsh or yash. Even csh arrays to some extent are between designed than ksh/bash's